# What is the uppercase version of "McDermott": "MCDERMOTT" or "McDERMOTT"?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

How should "McDermott" be typed in uppercase? Should the c after the M be lowercase?

MCDERMOTT or McDERMOTT

Which of the above is right?

Comment: MᶜDermott is written in mixed case. If you write only in uppercase alone, then you cannot use a lowercase letter. There is no "right" here because WE DO NOT WRITE THINGS IN ALL UPPERCASE UNLESS WE WANT YOU TO THINK WE ARE SCOLDING YOU.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response - Sr. Amala DeRose

Comment: "McDERMOTT" is not "all capitals".

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are asking this question with regard to upper case headings, etc. It is quite OK to write McDERMOTT rather than MCDERMOTT, as in

"McDERMOTT ANNOUNCES  RETIREMENT:

Australian fast bowler Craig McDermott today announced his retirement from Test cricket. However, he will continue to play one day cricket till the next world cup."

Comment: How do you use a lowercase letter in a format that admits only uppercase ones? For example, telegrams and bank statements.

Comment: When we type in formats for email, printing a newsletter, etc, it is possible to manually change the C to lowercase before saving.

Comment: Of course if the format does not allow it, the only option is MCDERMOTT!

Comment: (+1) It's not just "quite OK", it's recommended (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Language/2009_August_5#Using_a_lower_case_letter_for_all_caps_names_containing_.22Mc.22_or_.22Mac.22)

Comment: That makes it official for McCARTHY... Tragic that I cannot give you 3 upvotes but ony 1 (because you have found a very useful extract that clarifies this fine point of orthography) -- thanks a lot for the reference!

Comment: I would also like to buy you some spare upvotes for @English Student and for michael.hor257k.  Great (and absolutely correct) answer and great supporting notes.